# Dictionary with key and value list

Tags: c#

I can't figure out how to add to dictionary `_collection` new value from `registeredValues` list if the key already exists in `_collection`. I want to add to the same key another object from `registeredValues`. Or maybe I'm doing it wrong?

```
private readonly List<ThreePropertyHolder<string, string, string>> _registeredValues = new List<ThreePropertyHolder<string, string, string>>();

private Dictionary<string, List<object>> _collection = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

public Dictionary<string, List<object>> BlaBlaMethod()
{
    foreach (var reValues in _registeredValues)
    {
        _collection.Add(reValues.Value2, new List<object>{reValues.Value3});
    }
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with Tuples..?

Comment: @MethodMan No, not really.

Comment: It is a built in version of ThreePropertyHolder, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for tip, I'll definetly will take a look... :)

Comment: One other thing you might want to look in to is [`.ToLookup(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.100).aspx), your code will behave differently if you call `BlaBlaMethod()` multiple times because you are reusing `_collection`, but if you where not you could use `_registeredValues.ToLookup(x=>x.Value2, y=>y.Value3)`, that gives you a `Lookup<string, string>` which is a read only `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`, you may want to look in to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a different action if it is adding or it is updating. Use [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if the value exists and update the dictionary if it does.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<object>> BlaBlaMethod()
{
    foreach (var reValues in _registeredValues)
    {
        List<object> list;
        if(!_collection.TryGetValue(reValues.Value2, out list))
        {
            //The key was not there, add a new empty list to the dictionary.
            list = new List<object>();
            _collection.Add(reValues.Value2, list);
        }

        //Now, if we are adding or updating, we just need to add on to our list.
        list.Add(reValues.Value3);
    }
    return _collection;
}
```

Comment: Master, did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A LINQ version in case anyone's interested:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<object>> BlaBlaMethod()
{
    _collection = _collection
        .SelectMany(x => x.Value, (x, y) => new { x.Key, Value = y })
        .Concat(_registeredValues.Select(x => new { Key = x.Value2, Value = (object)x.Value3 }))
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => new List<object>(x));
    return _collection;
}
```

What this does:

1. Break `_collection` into key/value pairs.
2. Concatenate that with `_registeredValues` converted into key/value pairs.
3. Group by `Key`.
4. Convert it back to a dictionary.

This would be a bit simpler if `_collection` were defined as `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` rather than `Dictionary<string, List<object>>`. It would eliminate the need to cast to `object`, and you could just do `x.ToList()` instead of `new List<object>(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

By checking if the key already exists you can chose whether to add or updated an entry. Based on your sample it should work like this.

```
private readonly List<ThreePropertyHolder<string, string, string>> 
            _registeredValues = new List<ThreePropertyHolder<string, string, string>>();

private Dictionary<string, List<object>> _collection = new 
            Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

public Dictionary<string, List<object>> BlaBlaMethod()
{
    foreach (var reValues in _registeredValues)
    {
        if (_collection.ContainsKey(reValues.Value2))
        {
           _collection[reValues.Value2].Add(someOtherObject);
        }
        else
        {
           _collection.Add(
               reValues.Value2, 
               new List<object> { reValues.Value3 }
           );
        }
    }

    return _collection;
}
```

Comment: That is incorrect logic, you are overwriting the list, he wants to add on to the list. If you where just going to always overwrite it would be cheaper to just do `_collection[reValues.Value2] = new List<object>{reValues.Value3};` every time, that would overwrite when it exists and add when it does not.

Comment: Your update is better but it is still inefficient, don't do both `ContainsKey` and `_collection[reValues.Value2]`, that causes two dictionary lookups, if you use `TryGetValue` you can do it in a single lookup.